# SQL: Set variable to a cell value inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, variables, stored-procedures

I am trying to store a single cell value from one table in a variable (inside a stored procedure), so I can use it to edit a value in another table, but I keep getting a MSG 201:

```
Procedure or function 'spBookReturn' expects parameter '@bookID', which was not supplied.
```

Every time I try to run the sp where it all should happen:

```
CREATE PROC spBookReturn
@loanID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
@bookID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT

    AS
    BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION tBookReturn
        UPDATE BorrowedMaterial SET returned = 1, returnedDate = GETDATE();
        SET @bookID = (SELECT TOP 1 bookID FROM BorrowedMaterial WHERE loanID = @loanID ORBER BY returnedDate);
        UPDATE Books SET nHome = nHome + 1 WHERE ID = @bookID;
    COMMIT TRANSACTION tBookReturn;
    END;

EXEC spBookReturn '546A444A-3D8D-412E-876D-2053D575B54F'
```

Does anyone know why the way I have defined the @bookID variable doesn't work and how I can make it work?

Thanks.

EDIT:
I got two tables: `BorrowedMaterial` that includes the attributes `loanID, bookID, returned, returnedDate` and a few others that's not relevant.
The other table is `Books` and it includes `bookID, nHome` but not the `loanID`.

So by giving only the `loanID` as an input, I would like to update the `nHome`. I am trying to grab `bookID` since it is the only thing the two attributes got in common and this is where the issues happen.

Side note: I removed the variable @custID it spawned by mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*All* parameters for a procedure are Input parameters. If you declare a parameter as an `OUTPUT` parameter, it is still an input one, and if it doesn't have a default value *must* be supplied.

If you want the `OUTPUT` parameters to be option, which I personally find can be quite often, then give them a default value. I also add some additional logic to your procedure, as you should be using an `TRY...CATCH` and an `ORDER BY` in your query with a `TOP`.

```sql
CREATE PROC dbo.spBookReturn @loanID uniqueidentifier,
                             @bookID uniqueidentifier = NULL OUTPUT,
                             @custID uniqueidentifier = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY --If you are using tranasctions, make sure you have a ROLLBACK and THROW for errors
        BEGIN TRANSACTION tBookReturn
        UPDATE BorrowedMaterial
        SET returned = 1,
            returnedDate = GETDATE()
        WHERE loanID = @loanID;
        /*
        UPDATE BorrowedMaterial
        SET returnedDate = GETDATE()
        WHERE loanID = @loanID;
        */
        SET @bookID = (SELECT TOP 1 bookID
                       FROM BorrowedMaterial
                       WHERE loanID = @loanID
                       ORDER BY ???); --A TOP should have an ORDER BY

        UPDATE Books
        SET nHome = nHome + 1
        WHERE ID = @bookID; 

        COMMIT TRANSACTION tBookReturn;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION tBookReturn;
        THROW;
    END CATCH;

END;
```

Then you can execute the procedure as you have, without `@bookID` and `@custID` being passed. Of course, if you don't, their values will be "lost" in the calling statement. If you need them, then pass their values too in the `EXEC`:

```sql
DECLARE @bookID uniqueidentifier, @CustID uniqueidentifier;

EXEC dbo.spBookReturn @loanID, @bookID OUTPUT, @CustID OUTPUT;
--SELECT @bookID, @CustID;
```

Comment: You can merge two first `update`s. You can merge the `select` and follwing `update` also

Comment: Yes, they can, @Charlieface . I missed that when i was address some of the more fundamental problems ;)

Comment: Just thinking: if `@loanId` is unique (which it appears to be) then you don't need `@bookId`. But if it is not then the whole `update` doesn't make sense

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for the answer.
The reason I don't have default set for the variables is 1: it has been working fine till now and 2 more importantly I get incorrect syntax error as soon as I do. I tried to copy your code exactly, but the syntax error appears right under the `=` saying it was expecting `AS, FOR or WITH`.

@Charlieface I have updated the question, explaining why I'm even wasting time on `@bookID` :)

Comment: *"it has been working fine till now"* Then previously you must have been passing the parameters, @Kudue . *"I get incorrect syntax error as soon as I do"* Then what you're doing isn't the same as what I have done above.

Comment: @Larnu I copy/pasted your code into an empty query window in Microsoft SSMS. Could there be some options in SSMS, that I'm not aware of? Another thing though, in the end when you `declare` and so on, as far as I understand I'll still need to manually input the `bookID`. Isn't that correct? Cause that is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: *"I copy/pasted your code into an empty query window"* Did you fix the `ORDER BY ???` clause? What was the actual syntax error? And what do you mean by "input" them? If you mean pass them to the procedure, no, not if they have default values, @Kudue .

Comment: Also, don't blindly copy and paste code into your instance, @Kudue . If you don't understand it (which you clearly don't, as you would be able to fix the syntax error if so), you shouldn't be using it,

Comment: @Larnu
Yes, the only thing I was replacing the ??? with `returnedDate`. The exact error is: `Incorrect syntax near '='. Expecting ')', ',', AS, FOR, or WITH.`

Comment: Apologies, @Kudue , I had `OUTPUT = NULL`, not `= NULL OUTPUT`. Fixed but you could have spotted that one ;)

Comment: @Larnu haha, true. Getting tried here I guess :) Thanks a lot! Kinda struggling here. I'm running the EXEC like this:
`DECLARE @bookID uniqueidentifier;

EXEC dbo.spBookReturn '546A444A-3D8D-412E-876D-2053D575B54F', @bookID OUTPUT;` (I removed the `@custID` cause that has been a mistaske from the beginning). But now it throws me another error: `Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Procedure dbo.spBookReturn, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 41]
Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.` I know from earliere that I have to put the uniqueidentifier in between `' '` :(

Comment: The error can't be more clear there, @Kudue .

Comment: @Larnu You are right, the error is very clear. I do understand the error itself, but I do not see how/where it happens.
Apparently, I am the one who is sorry. I am very new at SQL. Next time I will go find a website for new learners only, cause I sure do understand that I know too little about SQL to get help here.

Answer (score 0):

```
 declare @bookID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
 declare @custID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
 declare @InResult;
 exec @InResult= spBookReturn '546A444A-3D8D-412E-876D-2053D575B54F',@bookID,@custID;
 select @bookID,@custID;
```

Seems, you need something like this

Answer (score 0):

My take on what you're looking for.  Because there are multiple DML statements (2 Updates) in a single transaction the XACT_ABORT ON option ensures a complete rollback.  Also, the THROW in the CATCH block is placed before the ROLLBACK to preserve the SQL generated error metadata.  Prior to executing the proc the OUTPUT variables are declared and placed in the parameter list (this omission is what was causing the initial error).

```
drop proc if exists dbo.spBookReturn;
 go
CREATE PROC dbo.spBookReturn 
   @loanID  uniqueidentifier,
   @bookID  uniqueidentifier OUTPUT,
   @custID  uniqueidentifier OUTPUT
AS
set nocount on;
set xact_abort on;

BEGIN TRANSACTION tBookReturn
BEGIN TRY
    declare @ins_bm        table(book_id        uniqueidentifier,
                                 cust_id        uniqueidentifier);

    UPDATE BorrowedMaterial
    SET returned = 1,
        returnedDate = GETDATE()
    output inserted.book_id, inserted.cust_id into @ins_bm
    WHERE loanID = @loanID;

    if @@rowcount=0
        begin
            select @bookID=0,
                   @custID=0;
            throw 50000, 'No update performed', 1;
        end
    else
        begin
            UPDATE b
            SET nHome = nHome + 1
            from Books b
            WHERE exists (select 1 
                          from @ins_bm bm
                          where b.ID = bm.book_id); 
            
            select top(1) @bookID=book_id,
                          @custID=cust_id
            from @ins_bm;
        end

    COMMIT TRANSACTION tBookReturn;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    THROW
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION tBookReturn;
END CATCH;
go

 declare @bookID    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
 declare @custID    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
 declare @InResult  int;

 exec @InResult=spBookReturn '546A444A-3D8D-412E-876D-2053D575B54F', @bookID output, @custID output;
 select @bookID, @custID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Larnu I figured out the only thing missing was a `=` on line 3 (and thanks to @charlieface I also got my code cleaned up a tiny bit):

```
CREATE PROC spBookReturn
@loanID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
@bookID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NULL OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION tBookReturn
    UPDATE BorrowedMaterial SET returned = 1, returnedDate = GETDATE();
    SET @bookID = (SELECT TOP 1 bookID FROM BorrowedMaterial WHERE loanID = @loanID 
    ORDER BY returnedDate);
    UPDATE Books SET nHome = nHome + 1 WHERE ID = @bookID;
COMMIT TRANSACTION tBookReturn;
END;

EXEC spBookReturn '546A444A-3D8D-412E-876D-2053D575B54F'
```